# padding-bottom no effect ？

Tags: html, css, flexbox

everyone, I have encountered a bit of an incomprehensible bug in css, although I found a solution, I still want to ask what is causing it。thanks.

```css
    #app {
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    #box {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-height: 400px;
      height: 1800px;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
    #flex1 {
      flex: 1;
    }
```

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="flex1">
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
      </div>
      <button>confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
````

question1: `height: 1800px;`no effect ？

question2: even removed `height: 1800px;`, `padding-bottom: 50px;`is also no effect？

The solution to all problems is

```
#box {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

why?

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a bug, this is just how it works with `flex`. Without even setting `shrink` or `grow` attributes with `flex` it will try to use the available space on larger screens and shrink to the minimum space on smaller screens.

Adding `height: 1800px;` is too broad and because you have the container `#app` set to `100vh` it will be forced to resize only using `height`. You have to specify a `min-height` instead so that the browser knows not to shrink lower the min specified height.

`padding-bottom` doesn't work when you remove the height because then the container is growing with the content & there is no room left in the container for it to have padding. You can see that in the screenshot below:

[image]

So in short, `flex-shrink: 0;` is the equivalent of telling the browser to use all of the height in the specified container = `1800px`. Adding a `min-height` would be the other alternative.

```css
#box {
  /*flex-shrink: 0;*/
}

#app {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 1800px;
  min-height: 1800px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#flex1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="flex1">
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
        <h1>123</h1>
      </div>
      <button>confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```